Family moved into house where a previous murder took place, man goes crazy after his pregnant wife cheats on him
I saw this movie awhile ago on Netflix and I think they took it off, can't remember the name. 
A man and his wife and son move into a house where a murder took place, turns out the man who used to live there with his family murdered his wife and children. 
The man in this movie works with film and he has a girl friend who works with him, he tries to convince her he is seeing ghosts and captures it on film to show her. 
The man's wife is pregnant and cheats on him, he sees it happening and holds a hammer briefly before running off. His wife goes missing, he thinks the man she was with killed her. 
He starts going more crazy and brings his friend from work to his home, he hears the ghost of a child who was murdered in his wall and pushes his friend into the wall, the police come and try to arrest him. 
He doesn't believe he's crazy but in the end he is running from the police in a well with his son and it turns out he murdered his wife. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. A while ago - how long ago? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to edit any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions

Oh I saw this too. It's a great movie. The name escapes me.

Netflix should be able to show you a list of all the movies you've seen. Maybe you'll recognize the title...?

You can see your viewing history on netflix here:
viewingactivity

I think you're looking for the 2014 film The Canal.
It features a husband who thinks his wife is cheating on him and a big part of the plot is him spiralling into madness.

David has been having a rough time lately, as he suspects that his wife Alice has been cheating on him with Alex, one of her work clients. This stress is compounded when David's work partner Claire gives him a reel of footage to be archived that shows that his house was the setting for a brutal murder in 1902. David's fears are confirmed when he follows Alice after work and sees her have sex with Alex. Devastated, David grabs a hammer but, coming to his senses, throws it into a nearby canal.

Here is the trailer:



